# OpenGL flat shading of non-planar polygons using TBOs

Tags: opengl, qt

I'm trying to implement flat shading for non-planar polygons (using a single normal vector per polygon) based on *buffer textures*, but I can't seem to figure out how to set up things correctly. The approach is as follows —

- I render n-gons using `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. Everything is stored index-based, so I use `glDrawElements()`. To know where one n-gon ends and the next one starts, I use the *primitive restart* approach.
- In the fragment shader, one has access to `gl_PrimitiveID`. In the rendering process, each n-gon is split into `(n-2)` triangles, each triangle has a unique `gl_PrimitiveID`.
- Each triangle can be linked back to its original n-gon as follows. Let's consider a mesh consisting of a pentagon, a triangle and a quad (in that order). The data stored in the first *buffer texture* is `0,0,0,1,2,2`. The pentagon (index `0`) is rendered as three triangles, the triangle (index `1`) is of course rendered as a single triangle, and the quad (index `2`) is rendered as two triangles. Using `gl_PrimitiveID`, the n-gon index can be obtained.
- Finally, there is a second *buffer texture* which contains one normal vector per original n-gon. The indices in the other buffer texture (i.e., `0`, `1` and `2` in the example) can be used to obtain the right normal vectors for each triangle.

Ok, to create the buffer textures, I use

```
GLuint faceIndexBuffer, faceIndexTexture, faceNormalBuffer, faceNormalTexture;

glGenBuffers(1, &faceIndexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, faceIndexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int)*FaceIDs.size(), FaceIDs.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glGenTextures(1, &faceIndexTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, faceIndexTexture);
// Unsigned integers (uint)
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_R32UI, faceIndexBuffer);

glGenBuffers(1, &faceNormalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, faceNormalBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, sizeof(QVector3D)*FaceNorms.size(), FaceNorms.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glGenTextures(1, &faceNormalTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, faceNormalTexture);
// RGB floats (vec3)
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGB32F, faceNormalBuffer);
```

where

```
QVector<unsigned int> FaceIDs;
QVector<QVector3D> FaceNorms;
```

Neither `FaceIDs` nor `FaceNorms` contains any data when the above code is run. To update the actual data, I use

```
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, faceIndexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int)*FaceIDs.size(), FaceIDs.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, faceNormalBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, sizeof(QVector3D)*FaceNorms.size(), FaceNorms.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

The other data (vertex information, i.e. coordinates and normals, and indices) are stored as VBOs and IBOs, wrapped in a VAO.

Relevant part of the fragment shader —

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform samplerBuffer primIdToFaceId;
layout(binding = 1) uniform samplerBuffer faceNormals;

int faceIndex = int(texelFetch(primIdToFaceId, gl_PrimitiveID).x);
vec3 norm = texelFetch(faceNormals, faceIndex).xyz;
```

Note that I use bindings in the shader, so I shouldn't have to use e.g.

```
uFaceIDs = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProg->programId(), "primIdToFaceId");
glUniform1i(uFaceIDs, 0);
uFaceNorms = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProg->programId(), "faceNormals");
glUniform1i(uFaceNorms, 1);
```

Unfortunately, something is apparently not set up in the correct way, because I don't obtain the right normals. This is the relevant logging information (Buffer 4 corresponds to the first TBO containing indices, Buffer 5 to the second one, containing normals) —

```
→ Log: QOpenGLDebugMessage("APISource", 131185, "Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 4 (bound to GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, usage hint is GL_STATIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.", "NotificationSeverity", "OtherType")
→ Log: QOpenGLDebugMessage("APISource", 131185, "Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 5 (bound to GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, usage hint is GL_STATIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.", "NotificationSeverity", "OtherType")
```

when creating/updating data, and

```
→ Log: QOpenGLDebugMessage("APISource", 131185, "Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 4 (bound to NONE, usage hint is GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.", "NotificationSeverity", "OtherType")
```

when rendering. **This last line here indicates what might be wrong, the first TBO is not bound anymore?** What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it! One of the TBOs is filled with *unsigned* integers, therefore `usamplerBuffer` has to be used instead of `samplerBuffer` —

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform usamplerBuffer primIdToFaceId;
layout(binding = 1) uniform samplerBuffer faceNormals;
```

Some debugging and results. Using

```
fColor = vec4(0.0, mod(gl_PrimitiveID,256)/255, 0.0, 1.0);
```

in the fragment shader results in

[image]

Note that in this setting, each triangle in an original n-gon has its own colour —

[image]

Using

```
fColor = vec4(0.0, mod(faceIndex,256)/255, 0.0, 1.0);
```

results in

[image]

Now all triangles in an n-gon share the same colour. Finally, using the code from the original post, we get the intended flat shading effect —

[image]

[Edit]
I still get the

```
→ Log: QOpenGLDebugMessage("APISource", 131185, "Buffer detailed info: Buffer object 4 (bound to NONE, usage hint is GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations.", "NotificationSeverity", "OtherType")
```

message, though it appears to be harmless.